# OS X taking a photo with the iSight using a command-line tool?

Tags: macos, command-line, webcam, isight

Is there a utility that is able to run from the command line to capture a single frame of the iSight inbuilt (and external?) camera? This would save to an image file. I have searched on Google and found utilities that link to websites that don't exist anymore.

Other options are:

- An Open Source GUI application I can hack into a command-line application?
- A GUI application being run for a small period of time, that can be configured via the command-line, temporary config files, AppleScript, etc?

This would be quite handy for creating apps for timelapses, security, fun etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"ImageSnap is a Public Domain command-line tool that lets you capture still images from an iSight or other video source. You might remember Axel Bauer's original isightcapture tool (that is no longer supported but still works on most systems). With ImageSnap I hope we'll be able to move forward and add features, adapt to the ever-changing Apple architectures, etc."

http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/

Comment: +1 ImageSnap works fine and the code is provided (with a public domain license).

Comment: ImageSnap is also installable thru [homebrew](http://brew.sh/): `brew install imagesnap`

Answer (score 5):

wacaw looks interesting, andcommand line: http://webcam-tools.sourceforge.net/

Comment: wacaw doesn't seem to work on Yosemite or El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a related [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/270968/21140), it seems that imagesnap no longer works on OSX10.11/El Capitan so another alternative is to install ffmpeg (MacPorts: `port install ffmpeg` or `brew install ffmpeg`) and run:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 30 -i "0" -vframes 1 out.jpg
```

Comment: `ffmpeg` 4.1 on 10.12 gives and error due to unsupported framerate. Removing the `-framerate` parameter altogether fixes the problem.

Comment: How do you grant permission for ffmpeg to run from a LaunchDaemon (to get past the "Failed to create AV capture input device: Cannot use FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)" ... it work from the command line.